# VSCODE - Clean output without path

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

How do I config my vscode output to look like the first image?

What I want:

[image: What I want]

What it actually looks like:

[image: What it actually looks like]

Comment: add to to settings,jason

Comment: "code-runner.showExecutionMessage": false,
"code-runner.clearPreviousOutput": true

Comment: It's `settings.json` and it's located in `{drive}:/Users/{your-name}/AppData/Roaming/Code/User/settings.json` if you use Windows 10 and used default settings for VS Code installation.